# Как реализовать в Monodevelop с GTK MessageBox?

Tags: c#, gtk, monodevelop

```
public static class MessageBox 
{ 
    public static void Show(Gtk.Window parent_window, DialogFlags flags, MessageType msgtype, ButtonsType btntype, string msg)
    { 
        MessageDialog md = newMessageDialog (parent_window, flags, msgtype, btntype, msg); 
        md.Run (); 
        md.Destroy(); 
    } 
    public static void Show(string msg)
    { 
        MessageDialog md = newMessageDialog (null, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Ok, msg);
        md.Run ();
        md.Destroy();
    }
}
```

При компиляции ругается на:

```
MessageBox.cs(3,52): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DialogFlags' could not be found. Are you missing `Gtk' using directive?
MessageBox.cs(3,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MessageType' could not be found. Are you missing `Gtk' using directive?
MessageBox.cs(3,92): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ButtonsType' could not be found. Are you missing `Gtk' using directive?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С MonoDevelop практически не работал, но судя по приведенному логу компиляции, вы забыли указать `using Gtk;` в начале файла:

> Are you missing `Gtk' using directive?

И не забудьте проверить, что необходимые сборки движка `Gtk` подключены к проекту.

Либо используйте полные имена классов и замените `DialogFlags` на `Gtk.DialogFlags` и т.д.